# PHP/MySQL: INSERT INTO with variable column name not working

Tags: php, mysql, variables, insert, insert-into

I've used `INSERT INTO` hundreds of times, but it has been a while and I have been driving myself crazy on this one:

```
//Database Connection

$movieID = 41154;
$userID = 15;
$vote = 'yes';

$postVote = mysql_query("INSERT INTO votes (movieID, userID, yesNo, $vote) VALUES ('$movieID', '$userID', 1, 1)");
```

I'm able to successfully connect to the database and get data from the `votes` table, but for some reason, I'm having trouble using `INSERT INTO`.

The following columns exist in the `vote` table: `movieID`, `userID`, `yesNo`, and `yes`.

Any thoughts on what I can do differently? I must be overlooking something very obvious.

Comment: Any errors? `$postVote = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`. Never asssume a query has succeeded. Plus, if movieid/userid are int fields, then don't quote the values.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! I had completely forgotten about `or die(mysql_error()`. Said it couldn't set duplicate key, which immediately lead me to see that I had forgotten to auto increment the primary key. Thanks again!

Comment: What is the proper thing to do with a question like this? It helped me, but I'm not sure it adds a lot of value to StackOverflow. Do I delete it?

Comment: probably post the answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Probably best to delete it, before the "mysql_*() functions are deprecated" brigade arrives and downvotes the question into oblivion.

Comment: I just arrived.  Please PDO.  I don't care about deprecation, but for the love of all non-injected SQL, please PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Using `... or die(mysql_error()`, as Marc B pointed out, lead me to my problem. This displayed the error that I couldn't set duplicate keys...I forgot to `auto increment` the primary key for the `votes` table. Thus it kept trying to create a `voteID` of `1` each time I tried to `INSERT INTO votes`.

```
$postVote = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

This solved my challenge. However, Tim G points out that using `PDO` is a much better approach than `mysql_query()`. With a little bit of reading, Tim G is probably right about PDO. Based on [PHPEveryday's Tutorial](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Portable-Connection-to-Database-P552.html), I could rewrite my Insert Statement as such:

```
// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

//set variables
$movieID = 41154;
$userID = 15;
$vote = 'yes';

//query/insert statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO votes (movieID,userID,yesNo,$vote) VALUES (:movieID,:userID, :yesNo, :$vote)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':movieID'=>$movieID,
                  ':userID'=>$userID)),
                  ':yesNo'=>1)),
                  ':$vote'=>1));
```

Instead of using `or die()`, `PDO` also has a different way of handling errors and exceptions. You can learn more about it on [PHPHash.org's Tutorial: PDO for MySQL - Error Handling](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Error_Handling).

Answer (score -1):

`INSERT INTO votes (movieID,userID,yesNo,$vote)`

and  replace `$vote` with `vote`